# Sql match against multiple words

Tags: mysql, sql, match

How do I run a query as so:

`SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE MATCH(firstname,middlename,lastname) AGAINST ('Adam','Dustin')`

It's failing when I use two words, such as Adam and Dustin, but it succeeds when I use one word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE MATCH(firstname,middlename,lastname) AGAINST ('Adam Dustin')`

Answer (score 1):

Try adding at end of line: IN BOOLEAN MODE (Before parentheses)

Example:

SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE MATCH(firstname,middlename,lastname) AGAINST ('Adam','Dustin' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Bye! :-D